# How to get color from int value on blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I've got int value (for red,green,blue) returned from a Web Service.

```
topR = 0.14
topG = 0.14
topB = 0.14


bottomR =0.62
bottomG =0.62
bottomB =0.62
```

From this value how to get color on blackberry.

Pls help me.

Comment: What do these represent? HSV? Without knowing if it's a percentage of something, or if it's some value clamped between 0 and 1, we can't really help out much.

Comment: Hi. when i parse the xml file,i got these value red 0.14 green 0.14 blue 0.14 like this.  Its RGB. i think first change to these value into percentage. there after how to get color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what your looking for

```
private int color =  0x00000000;  

public void setColor(int r, int g, int b)
{
     color = (255<<24) | (r<<16) | (g<<8) | b;
}
```

Comment: Hi., 255 is color range. and 24,16,8 are what represent. Could u explain me?